# Is there a way to get the carrier information of an iPhone user programmatically?

Tags: iphone

Aside from using the region to infer which carrier the user is under.

Answer (score 2):

1st Import `#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>` make sure you have the Framework installed too.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *phoneInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *phoneCarrier = [phoneInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSLog(@"Carrier = %@", [phoneCarrier carrierName]);
[phoneInfo release];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API in the SDK to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to inspect the IP address to determine carrier?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this product by my company to get the country & operator of mobile handsets: http://werwar.com , i'll set you up with a free trial but you send a post to our server from your app and it returns a string with the carrier (of known) and country.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old question and at the time there was no mechanism to check which carrier was used. But since iOS4 there is.

See the answers on this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900547/is-there-any-way-to-determine-if-the-iphone-is-roaming) which provides solution using CTTelephonyNetworkInfo