# How to detect programmatically iphone in Roaming

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

It is possible to detect programmatically iphone in Roaming ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900547/is-there-any-way-to-determine-if-the-iphone-is-roaming

Comment: Hope this will give you some clue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807939/does-ctcarrier-mobilenetworkcode-change-when-roaming