# Is it possible to turn off roaming from within an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, core-location

Can I detect when a user is traveling from place to place and have a button to switch off roaming to avoid roaming charges in my iPhone app?

This would correspond to the General->Network->Data roaming in Settings.

Answer (score 3):

No you can not, you ar not allowed to changes system settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the device "is roaming": https://stackoverflow.com/a/966618/696440 (have not tested this)