# iOS Network Connetivity Type

Tags: ios

My question is can a application be developed on iOS which could tell me if I am connected to my subscribed Network(Packet Data Connection) or any other roaming or WiFi network.

I am in a phase of a feasibility study of a project and the it completely depends on if this is possible in iOS or not.  in which I need to know if this is possible in iOS.

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938650/ios-detect-3g-or-wifi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at this: [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Basically, it's `+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForInternetConnection` and `+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForInternetConnection`. You can also listen to notifications to get informed when the network status changes.

Comment: To understand it more clearly, you mean to say that if I am subscribed to say AT&T and my Ios device start using data connection on any other Network or WiFi my application can give a Notification.

Comment: You can subscribe to notifications that will tell you that your iOS device can reach a certain host, that it is connected to the internet via WWAN or is connected via Wifi. It will not tell you that you're connected via AT&T's WWAN.

Comment: Is there a way I can know if the device is in roaming network? Sorry to ask so many question.

Comment: No, until today there is no way to detect this on a non-jailbroken device. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/966618/176248). BTW this is a Q&A site, so feel free to ask ;)