# iOS roaming detect like whats app for media download.

Tags: ios, cordova

In whats app, there is a settings for downloading an media during roaming. How can i achieve this in iOS, because detecting roaming in iOS is not easy without location services. If the user is in roaming then i dont want to download images.

Comment: Check out this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900547/is-there-any-way-to-determine-if-the-iphone-is-roaming) for more info.
Happy Coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to determine if the iphone is roaming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900547/is-there-any-way-to-determine-if-the-iphone-is-roaming)

Comment: But its jail broken devices, i am looking for non-jail broken devices